# Linkable section in screen fails for internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have to centralize an image in both axis and then add a linkable area to that image's top left area. This works great for webkit and ff but ie fails. My html code is this:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <img src="images/main_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#somelinkhere">Logo</a>
</div>
</body>
```

and my css code this:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1001px; 
    height: 626px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
div.content img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}
div.content a {
    width: 14%;
    height: 9%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -42%;
    left: 7%;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

this doesn't work for ie because i use an a tag displayed as inline-block positioned accordingly. Our friend ie doesn't show the linkable part in the screen at all because the text-indent. Can someone help a little bit? Thanks. This [demo](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/project.html) shall help you more i think.

Comment: What is your goal? Why not put an image inside a link? Or just a part of image should be linked? Also, you may create http://jsfiddle.net to see it in action.

Comment: Client requested to centralize an image in both axis and then add a linkable area to its top left area. That's why it's a little more complicated.

Comment: It should be centered inside of what? Content div only or on screen?

Comment: The image should be centered inside screen and the linkable area must be in image's top left corner like this [demo](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/project.html) . IE has problem with linkable area.

Comment: Hm. With your code I have a problem even in chrome. Let me check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eugqD/4/) (or results only [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eugqD/4/show/))

HTML is not changed. I assume that image has the same height/width as content div

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border:solid 1px blue;
    width: 1001px; 
    height: 626px;
    /*below will center div on screen */
    top: 50%;    
    margin: -313px auto 0;

}
div.content img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;    
    border:solid 1px white;
   /*top:-50% removed. Assuming that image has the same height/width as content div*/
}
div.content a {        
    width: 14%;
    height: 9%;    
    position: absolute;
    /* top: -something changed. Remember that absolutely positioned div is always positioned from closest parent relative div*/
    top: 10%;
    left: 7%;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border:solid 1px green;
}
```

Comment: Great but when i place a real image url then the link is working only for the green border of the linkable area for ie speakin always. See here [demo](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/test.html)

Comment: Mm... Not sure I understand you correctly. as far as I understand from your task, user should be moved to another page only when he clicks on linked area (that green area on your picture or inside green border on my jsfiddle)

Comment: Right but this still doesn't happen. It happens only for the border not inside. I ve put z-index:10 but nothing changed.

Comment: Oh. Strange. Let me check.

Comment: Maybe you have something else in your code not shown here? See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eugqD/7/) - I removed that logo text from inside a link and text-indent from css and see no problems at all (actually, same as with initial code). The only reason I see is that I'm using IE10 and when in IE7-9 mode it works differently from original versions of browser.

Comment: My code is the same 100% like this [here](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/test.html) and like yours, no differencies. Linkable is only the border.

Comment: Than try it without Logo text and text-indent. And what is a version of IE where you have a problem?

Comment: Did it [here](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/test.html) still same fault result. All ie versions, ie10 and below fail.

Comment: Cool! Interesting "feature". Now I see it.

Comment: Add to your css for `<a>` next code: `filter:alpha(opacity=0);background:white;opacity:0;` That works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a like you're creating a container, moving it to the bottom of the screen and then moving the image outside of it to the top-left corner of the screen. This last step is exactly what will fail in many cases. Child-elements usually will be hidden or cutted away when leaving their parent container. IE is more restrictive but correct in this case.

You can achieve your goal easier when you'll place the image outside the container. Keep in mind that body is a container by itself that is allways 100% wide and high (and cannot be changed to be 50% or whatsoever).

Here's the result on [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Awm/1/)

The Html:

```
<body>
this is the body
<img class="my_image" src="images/main_image.jpg" />
<div class="content">   
    This is the container
    <a href="#" >Logo</a>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
overflow: hidden;
color:silver;
}
div.content {
color:black;
background-color: silver;
position: relative;
width: 1001px; 
height: 626px;
top: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
.my_image {
width:160px;
height:60px;
border:1px solid red;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
}
div.content a {
    color:red;
font-size:14px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 7%;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

In general it's the best to avoid negative values. They're misinterpreted in many browsers and produce problems.

Comment: Could you please check this [demo](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/project.html) ?